# after upgrade to 12.04 wifi alone does not work, but wifi AND LAN together do!

Tags: 12.04, wireless, msi

I upgraded ubuntu to 12.04 on my MSI U100 Plus netbook and found that the wifi icon is missing and I have no internet connection. However, if I plug in the ethernet cable and reboot, then the computer connects to wireless too (and the wifi icon appears), and this connection persists after I remove the ethernet cable.

Now, my question is: how explain to 12.04 that it should connect wireless without a trick with the cable?

Answer (score 0):

Another issue I had seemed very much related; "Waiting for full network configuration" followed by "waiting 60 more seconds ..." during every boot. When I followed the advice from [bug #916890](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/916890) to *comment* out this line in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

both problems were resolved.